# I am designing a web application using MVC and Three tier architecture. I have got design issue with three tier architecture

Tags: java, design-patterns, web-applications

In DAO layer currently I am making methods for each type of database query like addDevice, deleteDevice, searchDevice, ifAlreadyRegistered ..... etc and It makes my DAO layer object very heavy .

Is there no way to have generic insert method , delete method , update method in DAO so that DAO layer will not be so heavy?

Comment: If you told what you're using to implement your DAOs, it would help (JPA, JDBC, something else?)

Comment: Then see @sigpwned answer. Use an ORM (JPA being the standard ORM API in Java, and Hibernate being a JPA implementation)

Answer (score 2):

Are you using an ORM like [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) to interface with the database? If not, you might want to give ORM a try. It can make working with a database much easier since you express your logic in the "native" programming language (like Java in your case) instead of SQL, and the ORM figures out the SQL for you. In Hibernate, for example, object updates look like this (from [this article](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-tools-1.html)):

```
transaction = session.beginTransaction();
Course course = (Course) session.get(Course.class, courseId);
course.setCourseName(courseName);
transaction.commit();
```

...instead of raw SQL. In cases where using ORM makes sense (which is not all cases), it can make your code a lot cleaner and more straightforward.

In broad strokes, a good example of a program where ORM *does* make sense is something like a CRM where you're just pushing objects around and doing simple reports; a good example of a program where ORM probably *does not* make sense is something like an analysis tool where you'll use heavily customized and carefully optimized SQL queries, in which case you'd probably spend more time working around the ORM than actually using it.

Comment: Yes, but performances of Object/Relational mappings are poor. Choosing a native object based database (ODBMS like [Versant](http://actian.com/products/versant)) may be an alternative, too.

Comment: I think that's a bit broad. Clearly they're Good Enough to have excellent implementations and wide adoption. To your point, though, ORM is not always The Right Thing. I've updated my post to call out a couple of examlpe cases when ORM may or may not be suitable, for reference. Ultimately, though, the choice of whether or not to use use ORM [largely boils down to what's right for the application your'e working on](http://sigpwned.com/content/should-i-use-orm-or-not-sure). (My blog post on the subject.)

Comment: So according to you i need to use hibernate (which is suitable in my case ). Is there not any other solution with my approach?

Comment: What you asked for -- "insert method , delete method , update method" -- sounds like ORM to me. But yes, there are other techniques you could try. You could also (for example): (a) define one static method called `insert` (for example) that takes an `Object` and basically `switch`es over the type and behaves accordingly, or throws an exception for unrecognized types; (b) create a `TypeHandler`interface with subclasses for all the DAO types in your system, and then have a `DAOPersister` object that instantiates and applies the appropriate class for the type being persisted. ORM is cleaner IMO.

Comment: thanks sigpwned it's very helpful...
So finally I think it would be better to follow standards and go with ORM rather than to create custom approach.

Comment: Glad it was helpful! ORM is a commitment, but if all you're doing is pushing objects around and light reporting, I think you'll find it's a time saver after the learning curve.